# Fullcalendar scheduler - header horizontal scroll error

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar scheduler v.5.3.2.
Horizontal scroll seems not to be working in timeline view header, whith a custom view of 6 weeks (resourceTimeline).

Here is my code:

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarTimeline, {
    
    initialView : 'resourceTimelineSixWeeks',
    views : {
        resourceTimelineSixWeeks : {
            type : 'resourceTimeline',
            duration : {
                weeks : 6
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the error i'm seeing because the header is not moving at all:
[displaced_header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nbTv.png)

I've tested it without a customview, and in IE 11, Chrome and Firefox with same bad result. ¿Is this a bug? ¿Someone who knows how to solve it?
Fullcalendar demo works fine: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceAreaColumns-grouping-demo

I also haven't found any info about this problem here or in github.

Comment: Strange. the only thing I can think of us either you forgot to load some required CSS, or there's a conflict with some other existing CSS in your page.

Comment: That was it! There was a conflict with fullcalendar's v.2.2.3. Thanks!